# Como centrar div verticalmente con flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

Quiero centrar el `<div="container">` verticalmente con flexbox, lo estoy aprendiendo pero no logro que se centre, estoy utilizando el `justify-content: center` para ajustarlo al centro (horizontalmente) y `align-items:center` (Para ajustarlo al centro verticalmente), pero solo me toma el justify-content el align-items no me lo toma.

Html:

```
<div class="container" style="height: 200px; width: 300px; background: #fff;">
        <form action="index_submit" method="get" accept-charset="utf-8">

            <input type="text" name="" id="inputuser" placeholder="Username">


            <input type="password" name="" id="inputpass" placeholder="Password">                   

            <button class="buton">Log in</button>
        </form>     
    </div>
```

CSS3

```
body{
    background: #978;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.container{
    display: flex;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Realmente no lo estás haciendo mal y está centrando verticalmente, pero no lo vemos porque el `body` se autoajusta al tamaño del div `container`. Pero si le damos una altura al body del `100%` en este caso, podrás ver como se centra el div correctamente.

```css
  html{ height:100%; }
  body{
      background: #978;
      margin:0;
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -moz-box;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: -webkit-flex;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      height:100%;
  }
  .container{
    height: 200px; 
    width: 300px; 
    background: #fff;      
  }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <form action="index_submit" method="get" accept-charset="utf-8">
    
      <input type="text" name="" id="inputuser" placeholder="Username">
      <input type="password" name="" id="inputpass" placeholder="Password">                   
      <button class="buton">Log in</button>
      
    </form>     
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```